# Defining the covariant derivative on bitensors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

Bitensors (tensors defined on two different points) are an extension of tensors found in some applications of general relativity, where objects such as the world function, parallel transport operator, heat kernel or propagator are bitensors of some kind. It is unfortunately not commonly done in the language of bundles, so finding details on the topic is hard.

As far as I can find, if we have two vector bundles $\pi_i : \mathcal{V}_i \to M$, $i = 1, 2$, (with typical fiber $V_i$) the bitensor bundle is defined in the following way :

First take the cartesian product of the spacetime involved, $M \times M$, and define the projection function :

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{pr}_1 : M \times M &\to& M\\
(p,q) &\mapsto& p
\end{eqnarray}

And similarly for $\mathrm{pr}_2$ with $q$. We then define the pullback bundle of $\pi_i$ by $\mathrm{pr}_2$, to get the bundle $\mathrm{pr}_i^* \mathcal{V}_i$, which is locally $\cong M \times M \times V_i$. The pushforward of our operators, $d\mathrm{pr}_i$, takes vectors of $TM \times TM$ to $TM$ so that

\begin{eqnarray}
[d\mathrm{pr}_i(X)](f)(p_1,p_2) = X_i(f(p_i))
\end{eqnarray}

where $X_i$ is the projection of $X$ in $TM \times TM$. The pushforward of the connection is defined so that, if we take $\nabla^i$ defined on $\mathrm{pr}_i V_i$, we get, for a vector $v$ on $\mathcal{V}_i$ and $t$ on $\mathrm{pr}_i V_i$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^i_{t} (v \circ \mathrm{pr}_i) = \nabla_{t_i} v
\end{eqnarray}

The bitensor bundle is then the tensor product bundle of the two, ie :

\begin{eqnarray}
\pi_{12} : \mathcal{V}_1 \boxtimes \mathcal{V}_2 &\to& M \times M
\end{eqnarray}

in which case we can consider the full derivative as

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^{12}_{t} (\alpha \otimes \beta) &=& \alpha \otimes (\nabla^2_{t} \beta) + (\nabla^1_t \alpha) \otimes \beta\\
&=& \alpha \otimes (\nabla_{t_2} \beta) + (\nabla_{t_1} \alpha) \otimes \beta
\end{eqnarray}

Now let's consider to test it a scalar bitensor, the world function $\sigma$, for instance, as its derivatives are known. The tensor product of the fiber is just $\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$. Then we have :

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^i_{t} (\sigma(p,q)) &=& \nabla^i_{t^{ab} e_a \otimes e_b} (\sigma(p,q))\\
&=& \nabla^i_{t^{ab} e_a \otimes e_b} (\sigma(p,q))
\end{eqnarray}

At that point, I'm not exactly sure what to do. What I would need is, I guess :

1. What is the tensor field $s$ such that $(s \circ \mathrm{pr_i})(p,q) = \sigma(p,q)$? Is it $\sigma(p,q)$ for a constant $p_j$, $i \neq j$, the one for the point we evaluated it at? Or is there a definition of connections for pullback bundles that do not require such a thing?
2. Concretely, how are we supposed to project our vector $t$ on $TM \times TM$ to its component? Is there some mapping from indices $ab$ to $\mu$? Is it simply the map $(a,b) \to a$, since I assume that in this case, the two are basically interchangeable?

In the physicist sort of way, the derivative is simply of course, for some coordinates $x,y$ of a patch around $p,q$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla_\mu \sigma(x,y) &=& \partial^x_{\mu} \sigma(x,y)
\end{eqnarray}